# Spring Security-flow after authentication entry point

Tags: rest, spring-security

I am trying to secure my REST services using spring security.My problem is ,I have stuck at authentication entry point.even though I have configured a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter,execution flow could not reach there.
Below is the XML configuration

```
<sec:http create-session="stateless" auto-config="false"
                authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
                entry-point-ref="http403EntryPoint"
                >

        <sec:form-login
            login-processing-url="/login"
            password-parameter="password"
            username-parameter="username"
            />

        <!-- <sec:custom-filter ref="tokenCreatorAndValidator" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"  /> -->

        <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" 
                       method="POST"
                       access="ROLE_USER" 
                       />
    </sec:http>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticatorDAO">
            </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="http403EntryPoint"
        class="com.app.login.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
```

code for AuthenticationEntryPoint is given below.

```
public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint{

   @Override
   public void commence( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
    AuthenticationException authException ) throws IOException{
       System.out.println("in RestAuthenticationEntrypoint\n--------------------------------------\n");
      response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized" );
   }
}
```

can anybody tell me what I m doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry cannot post comments hence posting this as answer.

Check if ExceptionTranslationFilter is getting called in your exiting configuration.

OR

Did you injected http403EntryPoint in ExceptionTranslationFilter?

```
 <bean id="etf" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="http403EntryPoint"/>
 </bean
```

>

Comment: Nope,I haven't injected entrypoint reference.Also I m getting no exceptions in error trace.After commence method is done,flow goes nowhere

Comment: If I add a custom filter in place of form_login_filter,user gets authenticated but then "Authentication required" error is thrown by AuthenticationEntryPoint.My question is,Why authenticationentrypoint is executed after user is successfully authenticated?